# Present deeply-nested view controller directly from anywhere whilst retaining hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm working on a big project and the stack is as follows.

I  have a UITabBarController and for each tab a UINavigationController, containing one or more UIViewControllers.

*UITabBarController > UINavigationController > UIViewController1 > UIViewController2 > ...*

The normal flow would be the user tapping through each view controller. But how can I open the app for example directly to `UIViewController2`, whilst retaining the hierarchy?

**I explicitely don't want to present a modal view from AppDelegate or push the view controller somewhere else**. The desired behaviour would be similar to chat apps, that open a specific chat `UIViewController2` (from a push notification, for example), but **still can go "back"** to the chat list view (`UIViewController1` in this example), even if the app was launched directly into `UIViewController2` and `UIViewController1` was never presented.

Another use-case would be to do the same but from another tab instead of AppDelegate. From somewhere in tab 2, open `UIViewController2` inside of tab 1.

How could this be achieved? I thought of different options, but wouldn't know how to implement them

- Build the hierarchy as normal but without presenting it to the user and, when `UIViewController2` is reached, present everything?
- Present `UIViewController2` and afterwards silently build the hierarchy above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how can I open the app for example directly to UIViewController2, whilst retaining the hierarchy?

By programmatically modifying the `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` array hierarchy.
Suppose, you are currently on `UIViewController2`, some sample code to build the backstack hierarchy can be like:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
UIViewController1 *VC1 = [UIViewController1 new]; 
[controllers insertObject:VC1 atIndex:(controllers.count - 1)]; // choose the index
self.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

A good place to perform this would be the `viewDidLoad` of the currently presented view controller.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I thought that might be the solution (as I mentioned), but somehow figured this would be much more complicated and would break everything.

Comment: @GuillermoSuárezAsencio glad to hear that :)

Comment: I'm currently using [URLNavigatior](https://github.com/devxoul/URLNavigator) to launch the vcs. Do you have an alternative/recommendation or a clever idea as to how one might implement the above discussed functionality directly into such a URL-based navigator? I can now open `/chat/<id>` and `/chats` separately, but would like to call `/chats/chat/<id>` and make the navigator do what we just discussed, open the chat and create the hierarchy above it. Just if you have an idea or know of a navigator that does such thing :)

Comment: Oh damn! URLNavigator looks pretty cool stuff but unfortunately I have no experience with it's workings. You should post this query on the library's github page for author's input on it.

Comment: I will play around a bit an otherwise post it to its github page, yes. But you don't know of any alternative that does that, right?